# $PGL_d(F)$ is 2-transitive but not 3-transitive if $d > 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, projective-geometry, permutations

An exercise asks to prove that: If $d > 2$, then the projective general linear group $PGL_d(F)$ of dimension $d$ over a field $F$ is 2-transitive but not 3-transitive on the set of points of the projective geometry $PG_{d-1}(F)$.  My question is on why the $d > 2$ assumption is necessary.

First, here is a proof of the assertion.  The projective points are the 1-dimensional subspaces of $F^d$ and $GL_d(F)$ acts on this set of projective points $\Lambda$. Given a nonzero vector $u=(u_1,\ldots,u_d)$ in $F^d$, let $[u_1,\ldots,u_d]$ denote the projective point containing $u$.  The action $\phi: GL_d(F) \rightarrow Sym(\Lambda)$ has kernel the scalar matrices $Z$ and so $PGL_d(F):=GL_d(F)/Z$ acts on $\Lambda$ faithfully. Define  $PGL_d(F)$ to be the image $\phi(GL_d(F))$.  We show this image is 2-transitive and not 3-transitive.

(i) Let $u,w,x,y \in F^d - \{0\}$ be such that $[u_1,\ldots,u_d] \ne [w_1,\ldots,w_d]$ and $[x_1,\ldots,x_d] \ne [y_1,\ldots,y_d]$.  Then $u$ and $w$ are linearly independent, as are $x$ and $y$.  Thus, the column vectors $u,w$ can be extended to a matrix $U$ whose columns form a basis for $F^d$, and similarly $x,y$ can be extended to a matrix $X$. Thus, $AU=X$ has a solution $A=XU^{-1}$ in $GL_d(F)$. Hence, $GL_d(F)$ is 2-transitive on the set of projective points $\Lambda$.

(ii) Pick any $u,v,x,y \in F^d - \{0\}$ such that $v \ne cu, y \ne cx, \forall c \in F$.  Let $w=u+v$ and $z \ne x+y$.  (For eg, in $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}$, take $u,v,w$ to be $e_1,e_2,e_1 + e_2$, and take $x,y$ arbitarily, but take $z = x+y+y \ne x+y$).  Then $\nexists A \in GL_d(F)$ that takes $(u,v,w)$ to $(x,y,z)$ because any such $A$ would be linear, and so since $w=u+v$, $A$ must map $w$ to $x+y$, whereas $z \ne x+y$.  (So, to prove $GL_d(F)$ is not 3-transitive, take the 3 distinct projective points to be such that the third is a linear combination (in fact a sum) of the first two, but in the image, the 3 distinct projective points are chosen so that the third is not a sum of the first two.)  Hence $PGL_d(F)$ is not 3-transitive.

I was looking at where the $d > 2$ condition is used in the proof.  Note that in (ii), to be able to choose $z$ to be a nonzero vector other than $x,y$ or $x+y$, we require that $|F^d - \{0 \}| \ge 4$, and this is guaranteed if $d > 2$ (or if $d=2$ but $|F| \ge 3$).  Only if $d=2$ AND $|F|=2$ is $|F^d - \{0\}|=3$, and in this case the choice of $w$ and $z$ is uniquely determined to be $w=u+v, z=x+y$, and so $GL_2(2)$ (and hence $PGL_2(2)$) is forced to be 3-transitive also. Now this argument implies that $PGL_2(F)$ is 3-transitive iff $|F| = 2$, but this result contradicts an earlier result I've seen (proved using linear fractional mappings) that $PGL_2(F)$ is sharply 3-transitive (even if $|F| \ge 3$). What am I missing?

Comment: For 3-transitive, did you show GL couldn't take one triple to any diagonal multiple of the other triple? In particular, z can be changed by a multiple.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: To show $PGL_d(F)$ is not 3-transitive, I had to choose the two triples in a particular manner (as described above), whereby the third component is linearly dependent on the first two components, but such that the dependence is chosen differently for the two triples. Does the proof look correct?

Comment: As far as I can tell the proof in (ii) is very wrong.

Comment: I see, in this projective geometry, $GL_d(F)$ acts on the 1-dimensional subspaces of $F^d$ rather than on the vectors of $F^d$, so the case in (ii) where $w=u+v$ but $z \ne x+y$ essentially doesn't arise if $d=2$, since as you prove below, the linear combination coefficients can all be assumed to be identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\langle \vec{u_1} \rangle = \{ c\vec{u_1}:c \in F \} , \langle \vec{u_2} \rangle, \langle \vec{u_3} \rangle$ be three distinct points in $$PG_{d-1}(F) = \{ \{ c \vec{v} : c \in F \} : \vec{0} \neq \vec{v} \in F^d \}$$
Let $\langle \vec{v_1} \rangle, \langle \vec{v_2} \rangle, \langle \vec{v_3} \rangle$ be three distinct points in $PG_{d-1}(F)$.

Suppose that $\vec{u_3} = \alpha_1 \vec{u_1} + \alpha_2 \vec{u_2}$ and $\vec{v_3} = \beta_1 \vec{v_1} + \beta_2 \vec{v_2}$. If $\alpha_i \neq 0$, then $\langle \alpha_i \vec{u_i} \rangle = \langle \vec{u_i} \rangle$. We cannot have $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 =0$ lest $\vec{u_3} = \vec{0}$. We cannot have $\alpha_i = 0$ lest $\langle \vec{u_3} \rangle = \langle \vec{u}_{3-i}\rangle$. Hence $\langle \alpha_i \vec{u_i} \rangle = \langle \vec{u_i} \rangle$ and we might as well choose our original $\vec{u}_i$ so that $\alpha_i = 1$.

The same argument lets us choose $\beta_i=1$.

Now both $\{ \vec{u}_1, \vec{u}_2 \}$ and $\{ \vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2 \}$ are linearly independent (by definition of distinct points in $PG_{d-1}(F)$), so we can find some matrix $A$ in $\operatorname{GL}_d(F)$ with $A\vec{u_i} = \vec{v_i}$ for $i=1,2$. Since $\vec{u_3} = \vec{u_1} + \vec{u_2}$ and $\vec{v_3} = \vec{v_1} + \vec{v_2}$ we get $A\vec{u_3} = A\vec{v_3}$. Hence $\bar A \in \operatorname{PGL}_d(F)$ takes the triples of points $\langle \vec{u_1} \rangle, \langle \vec{u_2} \rangle, \langle \vec{u_3} \rangle$ to the triple of points $\langle \vec{v_1} \rangle, \langle \vec{v_2} \rangle, \langle \vec{v_3} \rangle$.

If $d=2$, then every triple of points is of this form and $\operatorname{PGL}_d(F)$ is 3-transitive in its natural action.

If $d>2$, then replace $\vec{v}_3$ with a vector such that $\{ \vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, \vec{v_3} \}$ is linearly independent. As before we can ensure $\alpha_i=1$, but now $\beta_i$ do not exist. We still get that $$A(c \vec{u_3}) = A(c\vec{u_1}+c\vec{u_2}) = cA(\vec{u_1}) + cA(\vec{u_2}) = c\vec{v}_1 + c\vec{v_2},$$ but now this vector is not of the form $d \vec{v_3}$ for any $d \in F$ (unless $c=d=0$) since $\{ \vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, \vec{v_3} \}$ is linearly independent.

In other words, if $A(\langle \vec{u_i} \rangle) = \langle \vec{v_i} \rangle$ for $i=1,2$, then (choosing a multiple of $\vec{v_i}$ so that $A\vec{u_i} = \vec{v_i}$ for $i=1,2$) we have $A(\langle \vec{u_3} \rangle) = \langle \vec{v_1}+\vec{v_2} \rangle \neq \langle \vec{v_3} \rangle$, because $\langle \vec{v_1} + \vec{v_2} \rangle \cap \langle \vec{v_3} \rangle = \langle \vec{0}\rangle$. Hence $\operatorname{PGL}_d(F)$ does not act 3-transitively in its natural action if $d>2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\GL{\mathrm{GL}}$
Here is some hand-waiving argument:

To show that $\GL(d,F)$ acts 2-transitively on $F^d\setminus\{0\}$,
notice that any two vectors can be extended to a basis,
and $\GL$ brings any basis to another.
So in particular, $\GL$ beings a pair of vectors to another pair of vectors.

To see why $\GL$ is not necessarily 3-transitive,
notice that it acts linearly.
In particular, $u,v,u+v$ cannot be sent to three independent vectors.
This is not an obstacle when $d=2$, i.e., all triple of vectors are dependent.

For projective version (acting on $1$-dimensional subspaces),
choose representative vectors and then apply the argument above.